# Add columns for specific row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select et.entity, s.statusname AS Status, 
count(s.statusname) AS Count
from emp e
join status s ON e.statusid = s.statusid
join entity et ON e.entityid = e.entityid
where et.entityid = 2156
Group by et.entity, s.statusname
```

It provides the following results:

```
Column Header:  Entity | Status  | Count
Row 1:          Mobile | Active  | 2
Row 2:          Mobile | Setup   | 5
Row 3:          Exon   | Active  | 1
Row 4:          Trav   | Pending | 2
```

I want my results to look like this:

```
Column Header:  Entity | Active  | Setup  | Pending 
Row 1:          Mobile | 2       | 5      |  0 
Row 2:          Exon   | 1       | 0      |  0 
Row 3:          Trav   | 0       | 0      |  2
```

I've tried Transform and Pivot as well as union all, and this query:

```
select et.entity, s.statusname AS Status, 
countif(s.statusname = 'Active') Active,
countif(s.statusname = 'Setup') Setup,
countif(s.statusname = 'Pending') Pending
from emp e
join status s ON e.statusid = s.statusid
join entity et ON e.entityid = e.entityid
where et.entityid = 2156
Group by et.entity, s.statusname
```

It tells me:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I don't have the word 'with' in my statement.  I found another question on here with this info and I seem to have the same syntax as them.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the sample data used to produce the shown results.

Comment: It seems your error does not match your query - but there is a possibility that the batch you executed containing your statement also contains other statements that you do not show. Regardless, there is no COUNTIF function in tsql - the sql dialect used by SQL Server. Conditional aggregation can be used to achieve your output - searching on that term will find examples. Alternatively posting a script (even better - a fiddle) containing DDL and sample data would encourage others to help you build such a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a `countif()` function.  But you can easily do this using `sum()` and `case`:

```
select et.entity, 
       sum(case when s.statusname = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) Active,
       sum(case when s.statusname = 'Setup' then 1 else 0 end) Setup,
       sum(case when s.statusname = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) Pending
from emp e join
     status s 
     on e.statusid = s.statusid join
     entity et 
     on e.entityid = e.entityid
where et.entityid = 2156
group by et.entity;
```

Comment: @Charlieface . . . Yes.  Because `count(2) = count(1)`.  That just bothers me.  I think `sum()` is clearer on the intention.